# Pass md-input value from dialog to parent component function

Tags: angular, angular-material, angular-material2

I have a `md-input` field inside of a dialog window (the dialog is a child component). I need to have this value passed as a parameter for a function in the parent component.
How to do so?

Comment: https://angular.io/guide/component-interaction#component-interaction

Comment: have you tested the solution I provided ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Define a `shared.service` which passes the input value to the parent component:

```
import {Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { Subject } from 'rxjs';

@Injectable()
export class SharedService{
   public triggerParentMethod: Subject<string> = new Subject<string>();
}
```

In your `ParentComponent`, subscribe to the `triggerParentMethod` in constructor:

```
constructor(private sharedService:SharedService,public dialog: MdDialog){
    this.sharedService.triggerParentMethod.subscribe( someValueFromDialog =>{

        // Pass the value to the method here.
        this.someMethod(someValueFromDialog);

      });
}
```

Bind your `<md-input>` to some `[(ngModule)]`:

You can emit that input value from your dialog like this:

```
this.sharedService.triggerParentMethod.next(this.someField);
```

Link to [working demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-lgorb6?file=app%2Fdialog-overview-example-dialog.html).